# Cannot burn iso image to DVD using any burner

Tags: dvd, iso, burning

I tried to burn iso image to DVD using my Laptops DVD writer, but I am unable to do so.

I am using Ubuntu 10.10 and have used brasero, gnomebaker and acetoneiso burner. All of these burner throws the same error.i.e Power Calibration error
Following is the log file that is generated when trying brasero burner.

```
    Checking session consistency (brasero_burn_check_session_consistency brasero-burn.c:1744)
    BraseroBurnURI called brasero_job_get_action
    BraseroBurnURI called brasero_job_get_action
    BraseroBurnURI called brasero_job_set_output_size_for_current_track
    BraseroBurnURI stopping
    BraseroBurnURI called brasero_job_get_action
    BraseroBurnURI called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
    BraseroBurnURI output set (IMAGE) image = /tmp/brasero_tmp_2WO4LW.bin toc = none
    BraseroBurnURI called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
    BraseroBurnURI called brasero_job_get_action
    BraseroBurnURI called brasero_job_get_current_track
    BraseroBurnURI no burn:// URI found
    BraseroBurnURI stopping
    BraseroLocalTrack called brasero_job_get_action
    BraseroLocalTrack called brasero_job_get_action
    BraseroLocalTrack called brasero_job_set_output_size_for_current_track
    BraseroLocalTrack stopping
    BraseroLocalTrack called brasero_job_get_action
    BraseroLocalTrack called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
    BraseroLocalTrack output set (IMAGE) image = /tmp/brasero_tmp_SDO4LW.bin toc = none
    BraseroLocalTrack called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
    BraseroLocalTrack called brasero_job_get_action
    BraseroLocalTrack called brasero_job_get_current_track
    BraseroLocalTrack no remote URIs
    BraseroLocalTrack stopping
    BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_current_track
    BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_action
    BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_flags
    BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_action
    BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_action
    BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_fd_in
    BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_set_output_size_for_current_track
    BraseroChecksumImage stopping
    BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_current_track
    BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_action
    BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_flags
    BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_action
    BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
    BraseroChecksumImage output set (IMAGE) image = /tmp/brasero_tmp_9SN4LW.bin toc = none
    BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_session_output_size 
    BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_action
    BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_action
    BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_current_track  
    BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_input_type
    BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_set_current_action
    BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_fd_in
    BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_current_track
    BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_current_track
    BraseroChecksumImage Starting checksuming file /media/Others/Vbox_srijan/Downloads/iso/ubuntu-12.04-beta1-desktop-i386.iso (size = 736407552)
    BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_fd_out
    BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_current_track
    BraseroChecksumImage Setting new checksum (type = 2) 12e04b6893802d3b1935296bfbfe0910 ((null) before)
    BraseroChecksumImage Finished track successfully
    BraseroChecksumImage stopping
    BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_action
    BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_action
    BraseroLibburn unsupported operation
    BraseroLibburn deactivating
    BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_action
    BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_action
    BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_device
    BraseroLibburn Drive (/dev/sr0) init result = 1
    BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_flags
    BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_media
    BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_fd_in
    BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_tracks
    BraseroLibburn Setting multi 0
    BraseroLibburn Setting burnproof 1
    BraseroLibburn Setting dummy 0
    BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
    BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
    BraseroLibburn burn_drive_convert_fs_adr( /dev/sr0 )
    BraseroLibburn Writing
    BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_dangerous
    BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
    BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
    BraseroLibburn burn_drive_is_enumerable_adr( /dev/sr0 ) is true
    BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
    BraseroLibburn Async START UNIT succeeded after 0.1 seconds
    BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action

    BraseroLibburn DVD pre-track 01 : demand=736407552, cap=4706074624


    BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
    BraseroLibburn SCSI error condition on command 2Ah WRITE(10): [3 73 02] Power calibration area is full
    BraseroLibburn Closing
    BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_dangerous
    BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
    BraseroLibburn Libburn reported an error SCSI error on write(0,16): [3 73 02] Power calibration area is full
    BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_error
    BraseroLibburn finished with an error
    BraseroLibburn asked to stop because of an error
error       = 1
message = "SCSI error on write(0,16): [3 73 02] Power calibration area is full"
    BraseroLibburn stopping 
    Session error : SCSI error on write(0,16): [3 73 02] Power calibration area is full (brasero_burn_record brasero-burn.c:2862)
```

This is the error I am getting.

Answer (score 1):

> Power calibration error

Cleaning the drive lens helped in my case.

Answer (score 1):

just choose the minimal burning speed.

Answer (score 0):

> BraseroLibburn Libburn reported an error SCSI error on write(0,16):
>   [3 73 02] Power calibration area is full

This error message comes from the drive and is forwarded by Libburn and Brasero. I understand it indicates that the medium does not allow the drive to make laser beam experiments in a specially reserved area called PCA.

Most drives make such experiments if they do not find the particular medium product code in their internal database.

So best try a different medium. If the problem persists then it is likely a defect of the drive.

If this is a DVD-RW medium, then you could try to format it
e.g. by

```
dvd+rw-format -force /dev/sr0
```

or

```
xorriso -outdev /dev/sr0 -format full
```

or

```
cdrskin -v dev=/dev/sr0 blank=format_overwrite
```

In the hope that the drive will make the PCA re-usable.

I assume Brasero will not perform multi-session on formatted DVD-RW. But a first session should work. A DVD-RW can be brought back into unformatted state by

```
dvd+rw-format -blank=full /dev/sr0

xorriso -outdev /dev/sr0 -blank all

cdrskin -v dev=/dev/sr0 blank=all
```